# Python, Unicode: Working with badly formatted strings

Tags: unicode, utf-8, python-unicode, unicode-normalization, unicode-literals

I'm working on a Django app that gets data from a Redshift database. The people who wrote to this Redshift database made some bizarre choices. I'm trying to figure out how handle the fact that it has strings like this:

```
Let’s play! \xe2\x9a\xbd\xef\xb8\x8f
```

With psycopg2 I'm getting these into Python as

```
u'Let\u2019s play! \\xe2\\x9a\\xbd\\xef\\xb8\\x8f'
```

I'm supposed to render this as

> Let’s play! ⚽️

They're stored in the Redshift table as `varchar(65535)`. I'm using pyscopg2 to pull them into the app backend (Django 1.11, Python 2.7). They are being rendered with JavaScript on the front end.

Any suggestions would be appreciated -- I can't figure out any solution out at all.

Comment: You've got [mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) in the database.  It has a mix of encodings.  I'm unsure how you even got the result you did in psycopg2, because I couldn't find an encoder that could return that result.  Getting a U+2019 codepoint implies a Windows-125x encoder, but none of them return the UTF-8 remainder in Python without an error.  A correct UTF-8 encoding of the string would be `'Let\xe2\x80\x99s play! \xe2\x9a\xbd\xef\xb8\x8f'`

Comment: Whoops, you're right about what I'm getting from psycopg2. Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because there is a mix of encodings (what looks like Windows-1252 and hex-escaped UTF-8) you could try to post-process the entries if this mix is consistent.

Below is a regular expression to find sequences of hex escapes and replace them with a UTF-8 decoded equivalent:

```
import re

esc = re.compile(r'(?:\\x[0-9a-f]{2})+')

def fixer(m):
    return m.group().encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape').encode('latin1').decode('utf8')

s = u'Let\u2019s play! \\xe2\\x9a\\xbd\\xef\\xb8\\x8f'
f = esc.sub(fixer,s)
print repr(f)
print f
```

Output:

```
u'Let\u2019s play! \u26bd\ufe0f'
Let’s play! ⚽️
```

Comment: This works, thanks! Accepting this answer. Can you explain why you're encoding, decoding, encoding again, and decoding again? I've seen that as part of a lot of unicode solutions and I'm not really clear on why.

Comment: @NathanHinchey You *encode* to bytes, *decode* to Unicode.  `.encode('latin1')` is a trick to translate U+0000 to U+00FF directly to bytes 00-FF since the `latin1` character set is the first 256 codepoints of Unicode.  So starting from a Unicode string, turn it to bytes to be able to use the `unicode-escape` codec, but the result is another Unicode string, so encode again to bytes and decode to UTF8.